# Button Images not displaying correctly in interface builder (swift)

Tags: swift, interface-builder

I have a problem that is perplexing me to no end. I'm making a Mac App; part of the interface has the user select a basic waveform. I'm using a grid of gradient buttons, contained in a NSBox. In the interface builder preview, it looks like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkfjN.png). This is how I want it to look. However, when I actually run the application, the icons get all big and ugly, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nh2ak.png). After about three hours playing with the settings to no avail, I've come to the conclusion that I have no idea what I'm doing. Any thoughts?

Comment: could it be because of the image scale 1x 2x 3x

Comment: I'm not using the asset manager; the pictures are just stored in a folder. I just want them to be put in the button with no scaling at all.